# Helm install fails with "rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists" (ClusterRole)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm creating a Helm chart that can be installed in multiple namespaces. Among other resources it includes a ClusterRole.

Once the chart is installed correctly in one namespace I try to install it in another one but fails complaining about the already existing ClusterRole:

```
Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: existing resource conflict: kind: ClusterRole, namespace: , name: config-reader
helm.go:76: [debug] existing resource conflict: kind: ClusterRole, namespace: , name: config-reader
```

What's the workaround here? Is there a way to force Helm to ignore this existing resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole)

> ClusterRole, by contrast, is a non-namespaced resource.
>
> If you want to define a role within a namespace, use a Role; if you want to define a role cluster-wide, use a ClusterRole.

So, Either you can use the variable name for ClusterRole or use [lookup](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function) to check if the resource already exists.